# Issue with new Date() in IE

Tags: angular, typescript

How do i convert date in string as "12‎/‎27‎/‎2018" to "2018-12-27T00:00:00" this format in typescript.

```
const date = new Date(localDateTime);
```

localDateTime value is "12/27/2018". Above line works fine first time. But second time it gives invalid date. This is observed in IE browser.

Comment: So, what is the original input, what is coming in, can you provide the format on your computer, could you use external library like momentjs? What do you mean second time it gives invalid date?

Comment: input is "12‎/‎27‎/‎2018". it works fine for first time and second time it give invalid date. My findings is that if we give input as like this "2018-12-27T00:00:00" multiple times, it would work. Now i want to convert "12‎/‎27‎/‎2018" to "2018-12-27T00:00:00"